# On dealing with the misuse of bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I have been paying close attention to a particular user, https://stackoverflow.com/users/3616949/user3616949, who was recently caught for the manipulation of bounties. What this user did was quite ingenious really: after offering a bounty and getting an ample amount of attention and number of answers, he created another user which posted an answer. This user then transferred the bounty quantity to his other account. This account then posted a question, and used the bounty to get even more attention.

Ultimately, this kind of bounty manipulation allowed this particular user to use a single bounty amount to draw attention to many questions he had, rather than just one like it should be. My question is, **what can we as community members do to stop this from happening in the future**? Just as there are ways to catch serial upvoting and downvoting, why aren't there methods to catch the inappropriate movement of bounty reputation? Is such a feature possible to add?

Comment: You flag users that do this and leave it to moderators to clean it up.

Comment: Moderators already have the tools to detect and validate such fraudsters. It is also rare enough behaviour that there really is no need for automated tools.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that definitely solves the issue, but its often difficult to track the exact movement of reputation through multiple users

Comment: Not for moderators, it is not.

Comment: Related: [Bounty Fraud: quid pro quo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169547)

Comment: Clever though.Fraudsters have no limits.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is not something that needs additional tools. Moderators *already* have the tools to detect fraud like this.

Quoting from [Bounty Fraud: quid pro quo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169547/bounty-fraud-quid-pro-quo):

> [M]oderators have tools to detect this kind of activity and warn/punish those involved. We have reports that show us bounties that are awarded that can provide clear indications of circular or fraudulent bountying.

and

> It's also the most completely asinine way someone who has studied the system in an attempt to do this could possibly go about it, and is always detected. If the thousands of eyes watching the site at any given time don't pick up on it, irregular voting patterns and (as others have mentioned) recently awarded bounty reports quickly show the circular activity.